# angularjs promise then not called first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a follow up question for [Angularjs $http wait for response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361530/angularjs-http-wait-for-response)

Since i was unable to find a solution for that, i thought i will return a promise always and let my directive do the work in promise.then() function.

```
$scope.getVCard = function(id){

  var vcardKey = vcardKeyPrefix+id;

  var vCardFromLS = localStorageService.get(vCardKey);
  if(vCardFromLS){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve({data:localStorageService.get(vCardKey)});
    return deferred.promise;
  }
}
```

and in my directive i am using it as

```
(function(angular, app) {
  app.directive('popOver',["$window","$http",function($window,$http){
    return function(scope,elem,attrs){
      elem.on('mouseover',function(){
        console.log('mouseover');
        var promise = scope.$apply(attrs.popOver);
        promise.then(function(data){
          console.log('promise then called');
          console.log(data);
          //logic here
        });
        console.log('in directive again');
        console.log(data);
      });
    };
  }]);
})(angular, app);
```

But promise.then() is not getting invoked on first time.  It gets invoked and works fine on subsequent mouse overs.  What can be the issue?

I tried adding $scope.$apply() just before `return deferred.promise` but i am getting apply already in progress error.  What am i missing here?

Comment: You're only returning a promise if `vCardFromLS` is found. Are you sure it always exists?

Comment: yeah... it is always there. Actually there will be an if else in which if the item is not found i will trigger a $http request.

Comment: I think your use of `scope.$apply` confused Angular. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ASlH0io9QGuObUVWz5CC?p=preview) is a slighty rewritten version that seems to work okay.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because you are resolving it before returning it. I could be wrong though.

Try this:

```
$scope.getVCard = function(id){
  var vcardKey = vcardKeyPrefix+id,
    vCardFromLS = localStorageService.get(vCardKey),
    deferred = $q.defer();
  if(vCardFromLS){
    $timeout(function(){
      deferred.resolve({data:vCardFromLS});
    }, 100);
  } else {
    $timeout(function(){
      deferred.reject();
    }, 100);
  }
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Resolving a deferred before returning/using its promise isn't a problem.