# API call inside for loop in angular

Tags: angularjs, rest, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create an *Ionic* app and for this I have to make some **HTTP GET** request inside a for loop but it appears that angular does not wait for the data before showing them.

Here is a code I'm using.

```
$http.get(ApiUrl.get() + '/Threads' + '?access_token=' + $scope.userToken + filterString + "&filter[order]=created%20desc")
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    var i=0;

    for(thread in data)
    {
        $scope.threadObj = data[i];
        var threadId = $scope.threadObj.id;
        $scope.threadPostNumber;

        //On récupére chaque nombre de post
        $http.get(ApiUrl.get() + '/Threads/' + threadId + '/posts/count' + '?access_token=' + $scope.userToken)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.threadPostNumber = data.count;
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Connection error, please try again.");
                $location.path("/app/carte");
            });

        $scope.threadObj.count = $scope.threadPostNumber;
        $scope.threads[i] = $scope.threadObj;

        i++;
    }
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("Connection error, please try again.");
    $location.path("/app/carte");
});
```

The first **HTTP** get is done and the data can be show within the foreach but when I try to add additionnal data to the original ones with a second get request nothing is created or sometimes only the last value is shown for every one.

Comment: Sadly, you can't use $http like that. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17366158/3980115

Comment: @Vlad274 and is there a way to do this without the localstorage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem stems from the API call being asynchronous, and much slower than the for loop.

The `$http.get` posts the request, but it doesn't get the response until long after the for loop completes. As a consequence `$scope.threadPostNumber` inside the promise success callback is going to be set after it is assigned in:

```
$scope.threadObj.count = $scope.threadPostNumber
```

So effectively this assignment is useless.

In order to fix, use tail recursion or [Promise objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
in order to make the calls consecutive.

You can also properly scope the current thread object so that when the promise succeeds you will be modifying the correct thread:

```
$http.get(ApiUrl.get() + '/Threads' + '?access_token=' + $scope.userToken + filterString + "&filter[order]=created%20desc")
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    data.forEach(function(thread, i) {

        $scope.threads[i] = thread;

        var threadId = thread.id;

        $http.get(ApiUrl.get() + '/Threads/' + threadId + '/posts/count?access_token=' + $scope.userToken)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                $scope.threads[i].count = data.count;
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                alert('Connetion error, please try again.');
                $location.path('/app/carte');
            });
    });
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("Connection error, please try again.");
    $location.path("/app/carte");
});
```

Because this uses `forEach` ([see the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)), `thread` and `i` are scoped to the function, so for the lifetime of that function and any functions that it calls or creates (like the promise success callback), `thread` and `i` will remain the value passed into the function. This ensures that no matter what order the HTTP requests return in, you'll be setting `count` on the proper thread.